# How to determine which component has the program focus in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe4

I am using C++Builder XE4 32bit VCL platform. I am writing for Windows OS.

I have a MainForm with a lot of components on it.  When I press a keyboard arrow key and the Form's `OnShortCut` event is triggered, how do I determine which component has the program focus?

I have different actions which must be taken based on which component has the focus.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::FormShortCut(TWMKey &Msg, bool &Handled)
{
    //determine which component has the focus.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the global [`Screen->ActiveControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.ActiveControl) property:

> Indicates which control currently has input focus on the screen.
>
> Read `ActiveControl` to learn which windowed control object in the active form currently receives the input from the keyboard.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::FormShortCut(TWMKey &Msg, bool &Handled)
{
    TWinControl *ctrl = Screen->ActiveControl;
    if (ctrl == Control1)
    {
        // do something...
    }
    else if (ctrl == Control2)
    {
        // do something else...
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Or, you can use the Form's own [`ActiveControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ActiveControl) property:

> Specifies the control that has focus on the form.
>
> Use `ActiveControl` to get or set the control that has focus on the form. Only one control can have focus at a given time in an application.
>
> If the form does not have focus, `ActiveControl` is the control on the form that will receive focus when the form receives focus.

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::FormShortCut(TWMKey &Msg, bool &Handled)
{
    TWinControl *ctrl = this->ActiveControl;
    if (ctrl == Control1)
    {
        // do something...
    }
    else if (ctrl == Control2)
    {
        // do something else...
    }
    // and so on...
}
```